# Making array after explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I want to create an array from an input string. Before this code, I've tried explode, but the array remains length 1. Each string that I've tried is still one in array[0]. Here's my code so far:

```
public function word()
{
    $kata = array($this->kal->getHasil());
    if (!empty($kata)) {

        $n = count($kata)

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $imin = $i;
            for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
                if ($kata[$j] < $kata[$imin]) {
                    $imin = $j;
                }
            }
            $temp = $kata[$i];
            $kata[$i] = $kata[$imin];
            $kata[$imin] = $temp;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            echo "$kata[$i] ";
        }
    }
}

public function tokenize()
{
    $temp = $this->kal->getHasil();
    $token = explode(" ", $temp);
    return $token;
}

$hasil = $pp->tokenize();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($hasil); $i++) {
    $st = new stemming();
    $hasil[$i] = $pp->singkatan($hasil[$i]);
    $hasil[$i] = $st->stem($hasil[$i]);
    $hasil[$i] = $pp->stopWord($hasil[$i]);
    //echo "$hasil[$i] ";

    $hb = new hitungBobot($hasil[$i]);
    $hb->word();
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: your question is unclear, what is the value of $kata? edit with print_r($kata)

Comment: Your question is likely easily answered if you show your input and desired output, but in its current form it is unclear.

Comment: e.g. If i make the input like this "i eat pizza", the output should be 3. but, the result from that code is 111. $kata is to get the value of input AdrianCidAlmaguer MarkM

Comment: edit with more code, where is your explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a globar var, see the code:

```
    public function word(){ $kata = array($this->kal->getHasil());

       global $output;

        if(!empty($kata)){

                $ar= count($kata)
                $output += $ar;
            }

     public function tokenize() {
        $temp = $this->kal->getHasil();
        $token = explode(" ",$temp);
        return $token;
    }

    $output = 0;

    $hasil = $pp->tokenize();
                for($i=0; $i<sizeof($hasil); $i++) { 
                    $st = new stemming();
                    $hasil[$i] = $pp->singkatan($hasil[$i]);
                    $hasil[$i] = $st->stem($hasil[$i]);
                    $hasil[$i] = $pp->stopWord($hasil[$i]);
                    //echo "$hasil[$i] ";

                    $hb = new hitungBobot($hasil[$i]);  
                    $hb->word();
                }

echo $output;
```

Comment: But if I use value of $output for looping constraint, it doesn't work  
@AdrianCidAlmague

Comment: @Jessica why for looping and where?

Comment: in function word(). I have code for sorting after count $output.